# Count occurances of a specific value in columns of list of list in python

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have a list as following:

```
[[1,0,1,3],
 [2,0,1,3],
 [2,3,0,2]]
```

I would like a count of appearance of 3 in each 3 as a list:
((0,0),(1,1),(2,0),(3,2))

What is the best to do this? Do I need to transpose and then use list comprehension?

Comment: You could do that, or you could just write nested `for` loops. The outer loop goes by column, the inner loop counts by row.

Comment: Don't worry about finding the "best" way, just do it in a way that's reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to transpose, just keep a helper dictionary with counters:

```
m = [[1, 0, 1, 3], [2, 0, 1, 3], [2, 3, 0, 2]]

counters = {}

for j in range(len(m)):
    for i in range(len(m[j])):
        counters.setdefault(i, 0)
        counters[i] += m[j][i] == 3

print(tuple(counters.items()))
```

Prints:

```
((0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 0), (3, 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using dataframes

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame([[1,0,1,3],
 [2,0,1,3],
 [2,3,0,2]])

print((df==3).sum().sum())
3
```

There are 3 elements equals to 3.

Answer (score 1):

Took some time. I'm a bit rusty with comprehensions. Thanks for a nice exercise.

```
m = [[1, 0, 1, 3], 
     [2, 0, 1, 3], 
     [2, 3, 0, 2]]

result = list([x, list(m[y][x] for y in range(3)).count(3)] for x in range(4))

print(result)
```

Answer (score -2):

Will this work?

```
from collections import Counter
counter = Counter()
[counter.update(x) for x in ip_]
print(tuple(counter.items()))
```

Comment: Don't use list comprehensions for side effects